# installed metrics server in kubernetes cluster but getting 'ServiceUnavailable' error for ''kubectl top nodes"

Tags: kubernetes

I have a 3 master kubernetes cluster with kubernetes version v1.25.0

```
NAME              STATUS   ROLES           AGE    VERSION
master21.server   Ready    control-plane   77d    v1.25.0
master22.server   Ready    control-plane   22h    v1.25.0
master23.server   Ready    control-plane   265d   v1.25.0
worker31.server   Ready    worker          265d   v1.25.0
worker32.server   Ready    worker          265d   v1.25.0
```

I have installed metrics cluster  using following steps

downloaded  components.yaml from https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml

made following changes

```
- --kubelet-insecure-tls=true
- --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
```

then applied the yaml using;

```
kubectl apply -f components.yaml
```

I can see the pod deployed successfully without any, restart or error,
but when I execute ***kubectl top nodes*** getting following error

```
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get nodes.metrics.k8s.io)
```

Tried most of the things available in google associated with this error , nothing helped, can some one shed a light on this?

### Update

After sometime I was Checking the metrics pod logs and could see following error form all the other nodes(192.168.1.22 is one of the master server)

```
 failed to verify certificate: x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.1.22 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs"
```

After bit of searches, I have modified the metrics component yaml with following and , deployed again

```
 - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=Hostname,InternalDNS,InternalIP,ExternalDNS,ExternalIP
```

Now I'm getting  below error, for me it seems argumemt("- --kubelet-insecure-tls") given to to ignore TLS verificaion is not working properly ( either "- --kubelet-insecure-tls=true" OR "- --kubelet-insecure-tls") , if someone got into a same kind of problem and fixed, appreciate your inputs.

```
0218 08:16:22.070470       1 scraper.go:147] "Failed to scrape node, timeout to access kubelet" err="Get \"https://master23.server:10250/metrics/resource\": context deadline exceeded" node="master23.server" timeout="10s"
```

Comment: Look into metric server pod status and logs.

Comment: don't see an issue there

Comment: Oh I see there are some errors ,where metrics servers unable to communicate to one of the master server , but these error logs has started to appear after some time, because I checked pod logs as soon as I have executed these kube metrics commands , to identify a issue.. will go through the rest to see how to fix them.

Comment: Hi @kaushal47 is your issue resolved are you still facing some problems? revert back here if you are still facing some issues. If your issue is resolved please post the solution so that it will be helpful for remaining community members

Comment: I still have the problem, and I have updated the question with Update notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this issue fixed by doing following things;

1. deleted all current metric server components using

```
kubectl delete -f  components.yaml
```

downloaded the component.yaml

```
wget https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
```

2. added "- --kubelet-insecure-tls" ,and modified "- --kubelet-preferred-address-types=" in  -args section as below, changed metric-resolution to 30s ,
3. changed the --secure-port,containerPort to a custom port 4443( from 10250 to 4433 , because 10250 is already taken by the kubernetes api) and then allowed 4443 port in all the worker nodes and master node's firewalls

```
      - args:
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls=true
        - --cert-dir=/tmp
        - --secure-port=4443
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
        - --kubelet-use-node-status-port
        - --metric-resolution=30s
 
containerPort:4443
```

4)added hostNetwork: true at relevant place as below.

```
  hostNetwork: true
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
```

5. applied the component.yaml

```
kubectl apply -f components.yaml
```

6. check the apiservice status

```
kubectl get apiservice v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
```